# Are frat members more often involved in rape?

Tags: sexual-abuse, university

This is more about a common prejudice (or not) about fraternities than about some famous claim.  I want to know whether frat members rape more than the common non-fraternity member?

In [Opinion: 'Rapebait' e-mail reveals dark side of frat culture - CNN](https://www.cnn.com/2013/10/09/opinion/foubert-fraternities-rape/),
 John Foubert says:

> [(A study)](http://www.academia.edu/163846/Foubert_J._D._Newberry_J._T._and_Tatum_J._L._2007_._Behavior_differences_seven_months_later_Effects_of_a_rape_prevention_program_on_first-year_men_who_join_fraternities._NASPA_Journal_44_728-749)
>   I published in 2007 with my colleagues Jerry Tatum and J.T. Newberry found that fraternity men were three times more likely to commit rape than other men on college campuses. It was the third study showing that fraternity men are three times more likely to rape.

Comment: [Welcome to Skeptics!](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/welcome-to-new-users) Please [provide some references](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/882/what-are-the-attributes-of-a-good-question/883#883) to places where this claim is being made. Also, it is currently unclear whether you mean during their membership, or in their lifetime.

Comment: This notable claim is *similar* without actually making the claim you are hinting at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Campus_rape#Perpetuation_by_college_fraternities

Comment: @Oddthinking I think *the answer* could qualify the question better in this case.

Comment: Not sure why this came up, but not voting to close as this is an ancient question on the site.

Comment: I'm voting to close because this question does not meet modern standards for a question on this site.  As an ancient question, it is unlikely to receive new answers even if left open.  And cleaning up old questions makes it easier to justify stronger standards on new questions.

Answer (score -4):

The Women Sexual Victimization study (Fisher, Cullen, & Turner, 2006), in a sample covering over 4000 women across the United States, indicates that women report instances of Rape at around 3.5% before University and 11% after university. There is sufficient evidence to suggest a concerning trend regarding sexual victimization at University.

You should check out Bannon, R. S., Brosi, M. W., & Foubert, J. D. (2013). Sorority women’s and fraternity men's rape myth acceptance and bystander intervention attitudes.  http://www.degruyter.com/view/j/jsarp

Comment: Is your first reference relevant to fraternities? Do people in fraternities behave worse than other similar people not in them? In these studies, confounding factors are *everything*.